# Call variable outside a method javafx

Tags: java, javafx

I made a progressbar and it works perfectly. The only issue is that i want to show the progress percentage. first some background information: Netwerk reads in a large file(=bestand) line by line and everytime it reads a line a counter goes up by 1. So the percentage i want to get is the (counter/1380)*100 with 1380 is the number of lines the scanner reads in. When I run it Netwerk reads in the file while the progressbar is running and the progressbar stops when the scanner is ready (so this works perfectly). But the percentage doesn't upgrade. When I debugged I discovered that updateprogress is called after Netwerk has finished reading and therefore the percentage stays at -100%. Does someone have a solution for this?

```
                    Task<Integer> task = new Task<Integer>() {
                    @Override
                    public Integer call() throws Exception {
                        n = new Netwerk(bestand);
                        updateProgress(((n.getTeller()/1380)*100), 100);
                        return null;
                    }

                };

                pb = new ProgressBar();
                pb.progressProperty().bind(task.progressProperty());
                Label lg = new Label();
                lg.textProperty().bind(Bindings.format("Even geduld... %.0f%%", 
                task.progressProperty().multiply(100)));
                task.setOnSucceeded(new EventHandler<WorkerStateEvent>() {

                    @Override
                    public void handle(WorkerStateEvent event) {

                        progressStage.close();
                        SaveStage = new Stage();
                        //initStage
                    }
                });
                new Thread(task).start();
```

So what happens is that I have a thread with a task in it, the task;
1. makes a Netwerk that reads in the document and increments the counter( i tested the counter and it works) 
2. Updateprogress() to update the counter has well

then i bind the task to the progressbar and i bind the label with a textProperty. The problem is that the label doesn't update.

[image]

Comment: Sorry, that is completely unclear. "I made a `ProgressBar` and it works perfectly." So it shows the progress, presumably. "The only issue is that I want to show the progress percentage". So what is the progress bar showing? I cannot really see any connection between your description and your code (and cannot really understand your description). Can you create a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), explain what you are trying to do and how the example behaves differently from it?

Comment: @James_D i guess show the `ProgressBar` is not necessary, bar is working, the problem for the OP here is to get the percentage outside the inner class...

Comment: OK, maybe. But then why not just do `progressBar.getProgress()`?

Comment: I think you should take a look at the observer pattern: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern

Comment: @James_D sorry if i was unclear, but getProgress() doesn't work for some strange reason

Comment: @James_D i hope this question is better... sorry!

Comment: Why won't you post an actual [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), as you have been asked repeatedly? Please also read http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic : "Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself." And no, this question is not any better at all. Why would the progress change when you are only calling `updateProgress(...)` once?

Comment: @James_D i added some code and some extra info, i'm reading the documents

Answer (score 0):

Define a variable as attribute of your class

```
class YourClass { 
    private volatile int percentage;
```

Initialize it when you start your `ProgressBar`, and assign it inside `Task`:

```
Task task = new Task<Integer>() {
@Override
public Integer call() throws Exception {
    n = new Netwerk(bestand);

    // assign here the percentage variable
    percentage = n.getPercentage();

    if (n.getTeller() == 1380) {
        return null;
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: You should declare it as `volatile`, since you are referencing it from two different threads.

Comment: no it doesn't work, i want to show the percentage in a label so when i make the label and print percentage it keeps printing 0

Comment: If you can get correct value inside `call()` It must work. But depends where you initialize `percentage`. I initialized it just before the method, but this is not valid in a longer code, make `percentage` an attribute of the `Java class`, initialize it when you start your `ProgressBar` and you will get the correct result...